# Why is my OpenTelemetry java extension not working

Tags: java, open-telemetry

I have created an extension to add some comment in the sql query. For this I have created a `MySQLAddCommentInstrumentation.java` class to make changes to `query` in `Statement.java` class.
Also there is one `MySQLAddCommentInstrumentationModule.java` class which adds this instrumentation (`MySQLAddCommentInstrumentation`) to its list.

When I build this extension and run my app, I do not see the comment in the query under db.statement zipkin log.

Instrumentation Class - MySQLAddCommentInstrumentation.java
Path - examples/extension/src/main/java/com/example/javaagent/mysqlinstrumentation/MySQLAddCommentInstrumentation.java

```
package com.example.javaagent.mysqlinstrumentation;

import static io.opentelemetry.javaagent.extension.matcher.AgentElementMatchers.implementsInterface;
import static net.bytebuddy.matcher.ElementMatchers.named;
import static net.bytebuddy.matcher.ElementMatchers.namedOneOf;

import io.opentelemetry.javaagent.extension.instrumentation.TypeInstrumentation;
import io.opentelemetry.javaagent.extension.instrumentation.TypeTransformer;
import net.bytebuddy.asm.Advice;
import net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription;
import net.bytebuddy.matcher.ElementMatcher;
import net.bytebuddy.matcher.ElementMatchers;

public class MySQLAddCommentInstrumentation implements TypeInstrumentation {

  @Override
  public ElementMatcher<TypeDescription> typeMatcher() {
    System.out.println("Inside MYSQL- 1.1");
    return implementsInterface(named("java.sql.Statement"));
  }

  public void transform(TypeTransformer transformer) {
    System.out.println("Inside MYSQL- 1.2");

    transformer.applyAdviceToMethod(
        namedOneOf("executeQuery")
            .and(ElementMatchers.takesArgument(0, String.class))
            .and(ElementMatchers.isPublic()),
        MySQLAddCommentInstrumentation.class.getName() + "$StatementAddCommentAdvice");

    System.out.println("Inside MYSQL- 1.3");
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unused")
  public static class StatementAddCommentAdvice {

    @Advice.OnMethodEnter(suppress = Throwable.class)
    public static void onEnter(@Advice.Argument(value = 0, readOnly = false) String sql) {
      System.out.println("Inside MYSQL- 1.4");

      sql = sql + " -- some comment";

      System.out.println("Inside MYSQL- 1.5");
    }
  }
```

InstrumentationModule - MySQLAddCommentInstrumentationModule.java
Path - examples/extension/src/main/java/com/example/javaagent/mysqlinstrumentation/MySQLAddCommentInstrumentationModule.java

```
package com.example.javaagent.mysqlinstrumentation;

import static java.util.Collections.singletonList;

import com.google.auto.service.AutoService;
import io.opentelemetry.javaagent.extension.instrumentation.InstrumentationModule;
import io.opentelemetry.javaagent.extension.instrumentation.TypeInstrumentation;
import io.opentelemetry.javaagent.extension.matcher.AgentElementMatchers;
import java.util.List;
import net.bytebuddy.matcher.ElementMatcher;


@AutoService(InstrumentationModule.class)
public final class MySQLAddCommentInstrumentationModule extends InstrumentationModule {
  public MySQLAddCommentInstrumentationModule() {
    super("jdbc");
  }

  @Override
  public int order() {
    return 1;
  }

  @Override
  public ElementMatcher.Junction<ClassLoader> classLoaderMatcher() {
    return AgentElementMatchers.hasClassesNamed("java.sql.Statement");
  }

  @Override
  public List<TypeInstrumentation> typeInstrumentations() {
    return singletonList(new MySQLAddCommentInstrumentation());
  }
}
```

Code where this instrumentations is expected to run:

```
try {
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, uname, password);
            Statement statement = con.createStatement();
            System.out.println(query);
            ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery(query);
            System.out.println(query);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I have run `./gradlew build` inside examples/extension and used that extension jar to run my application

```
java -javaagent:/Users/vaibhavpaharia/Downloads/opentelemetry-javaagent.jar \
     -Dotel.javaagent.extensions=/Users/vaibhavpaharia/ok/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/examples/extension/build/libs/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation-extension-demo-1.0-all.jar  \
     -Dotel.service.name=simpleapplication \
     -Dotel.traces.exporter=zipkin \
     -Dserver.port=8080 \
     -jar /Users/vaibhavpaharia/Downloads/simpleproject/target/simpleproject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

After running the application with agent and extension I see that other extensions are working fine which are present in the example folder.
Also, I tried changing the order method in MySQLAddCommentInstrumentationModule.java and returned 0 from there, in that case `Inside MYSQL- 1.1`, `Inside MYSQL- 1.2` and `Inside MYSQL- 1.3` got printed so it seems the new extension is recognised while running the application. It never prints `Inside MYSQL- 1.4` and `Inside MYSQL- 1.5`. Also, the traces stop coming to zipkin.

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Sharing is only supported for boot loader classes because bootstrap classpath has been appended
[otel.javaagent 2023-01-05 14:50:31:010 +0530] [main] INFO io.opentelemetry.javaagent.tooling.VersionLogger - opentelemetry-javaagent - version: 1.20.2
Inside MYSQL- 1.1
Inside MYSQL- 1.2
Inside MYSQL- 1.3
[otel.javaagent 2023-01-05 14:50:34:068 +0530] [main] INFO io.opentelemetry.javaagent.shaded.instrumentation.jmx.engine.JmxMetricInsight - Empty JMX configuration, no metrics will be collected for InstrumentationScope io.opentelemetry.jmx

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.0.1)

2023-01-05T14:50:35.687+05:30  INFO 85143 --- [           main] c.e.s.SimpleprojectApplication           : Starting SimpleprojectApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 18.0.2 with PID 85143 (/Users/vaibhavpaharia/Downloads/simpleproject/target/simpleproject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by vaibhavpaharia in /Users/vaibhavpaharia)
2023-01-05T14:50:35.700+05:30  INFO 85143 --- [           main] c.e.s.SimpleprojectApplication           : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-01-05T14:50:37.451+05:30  INFO 85143 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-01-05T14:50:37.531+05:30  INFO 85143 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-01-05T14:50:37.531+05:30  INFO 85143 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.4]
2023-01-05T14:50:37.643+05:30  INFO 85143 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-01-05T14:50:37.645+05:30  INFO 85143 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1859 ms
2023-01-05T14:50:38.254+05:30  INFO 85143 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2023-01-05T14:50:38.266+05:30  INFO 85143 --- [           main] c.e.s.SimpleprojectApplication           : Started SimpleprojectApplication in 3.409 seconds (process running for 7.566)
```

Comment: Try to exclude classLoaderMatcher() at all. It enables classloader which will load `java.sql.Statement` but may be unable to load other classes. Use the default loader.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set the `readOnly = false` option on the `@Argument` annotation , otherwise the advice code will not overwrite the original value:

```java
    @Advice.OnMethodEnter(suppress = Throwable.class)
    public static void onEnter(@Advice.Argument(value = 0, readOnly = false) String sql) {
      System.out.println("Inside MYSQL-1.4");

      sql = sql + " -- some comment";

      System.out.println("Inside MYSQL- 1.5");
    }
```

Comment: Updated the Advice code. Still not working. 
Also, I am assuming that if the flow reaches inside the advice, System.out.println("Inside MYSQL-1.4") and System.out.println("Inside MYSQL-1.5") should be printed. But this too is not coming when I am making a call to db from application.

Comment: Have you tried running the agent in the debug mode? (`-Dotel.javaagent.debug=true`)
Perhaps there are some errors in the output logs that might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, was able to fix this using the debug option